# What's the proper way to import variables from a different file?

Tags: python, import

I have a python script which requires a list of input parameters of various classes. I've put them in a separate .py file, so it can be edited separately, and I want to load them. I'm currently using something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/file')
import myfile as params
print(params.a)
```

I have two issues with this method:

1. I cannot use a variable name for the name of the input file
2. It would make more sense to save the parameters in some sort of text file rather than a python module, but it seems it would take considerable effort to encode and decode them.

What is the proper way of doing this in python?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want, but there is very little effort required to decode a file if you use something like YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `__import__` function so that you can use a variable to specify the module name:

```
module_name = 'myfile'
params = __import__(module_name)
```

There's nothing wrong to use a dedicated module to store configuration/settings-related variables as long as the file isn't particularly large. If the file is so large that it noticeably affects loading time and memory usage, you should then consider using alternative indexable storage solutions such as sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

```
from myfile import *
```

This will import all objects and methods from file. Now you may use variables